# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: null near line 1,

Tags: hibernate

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
> org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token:
> null near line 1, column 226 [SELECT COUNT(*) FROM
> com.pmp.vupadhi.model.EmpLeave  WHERE ((start_date >=:startdate AND
> start_date <=:enddate) OR (end_date >=:startdate AND end_date
> <=:enddate)) AND em_id =:id AND (leave_status !=103 AND leave_status
> !=104]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a closing parenthesis `)` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try `<>` operator for not equal to.

```
leave_status <> 104
```

Also give an alias and then do COUNT(alias) instead of a *.

Comment: still getting the same error but in column 235......thanks for u r effort

Answer (score 0):

You might have a null parameter even when you do not expect that.
Try logging the parameters like described in https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-logging-levels and check for null values.